# AssertMacros.h not found exception in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

im facing this problem described in the title. After updating xcode and mac os to mavericks, xcode throws this error...Any ideas how to fix that? (iPhone project)

Mac OSX Mavericks
Xcode Version 5.0.1

EDIT:

Problem fixed. Had to install command line tools manually from apple's developer website.

Comment: Your terminology is a little bit confusing, but I presume you mean that XCode can no longer find the file in question when it's `#import`d. Are you sure that your XCode installation is good? This file is in *every* SDK I have all the way back to an iOS 4.3 SDK.

Comment: it ran before the update to 5.0.1

Comment: @sNore Can you share the error log?

Comment: Yes.
Shows me the error at this line #include </usr/include/AssertMacros.h>
Log message: '/usr/include/AssertMacros.h' file not found